# Does overriding hash and eql in ruby affect performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How much would the following affect performance? I am worried that this may have a big effect because I use this everywhere. I'm not sure where each of them is called (i.e., `include?` calls these methods and so does `|`), but any other major methods may cause performance slowdown.

```
class Source
  def hash
    url.hash
  end
  def ==(other)
    eql?(other)
  end
  def eql?(other)
    return false if other == false || url == nil || other == nil || other.url == nil
    url == other.url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding a method per se does not affect performance, but the implementation of the method matters. Your method is bad because it has redundant things. It could be better written as:

```
def eql?(other)
  url = self.url and other and url == other.url
end
```

The `url = self.url` is memoization.

---

You originally have five conditions to make it true:

- not other == false
- not url == nil
- not other == nil
- not other.url == nil
- url == other.url

Among them,

- No1 and No3 can be put togher by putting `url` in the condition.
- No4 is redundant under No2 and No5 because if `url` is not `nil`, and `other.url` is `url`, then `other.url` is not `nil`.

Comment: Thanks @sawa, I dont understand.  How does the assignment combine with the logic, could you break that out for me.  I think i dont understand url = self.url as a condition?

Comment: I just dont understand how this is memoization since the block of code is executed 'every' time...??

Comment: It calls once instead of twice.

Comment: When I run this code and I call .eql? repeatedly, it executes the code every time (ie. when i add the begin; end code around)